# Recursion in c to print characters

Tags: c, recursion

I need to write a function that receive two arguments, n and 2 characters, from void main and then to print the first character n times and the second character n*2. I can only use recursion, not strings or anything more advanced. I tried different variations but after the recursion the prog isn't going down to the statement of printf to print ch2 twice.
can someone help?

Thanks in advance.

```
#include<stdio.h>
void string_rec(int num, char ch1, char ch2)
{
    if (num == 0)
        return 0;
    else
    {
        printf("%c",ch1);
        return string_rec(num-1, ch1, ch2);
        printf("%c%c", ch2, ch2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please turn on compiler warnings; a `void`-function should not return anything.

Answer (score 8):

It's not going there because `return` stops the function. The second `printf` is unreachable. Remove that `return`.

```
void string_rec(int num, char ch1, char ch2)
{
    if (num == 0)
        return;
    else
    {
        printf("%c", ch1);
        string_rec(num - 1, ch1, ch2); // don't return here
        printf("%c%c", ch2, ch2);
    }
}
int main() {
    string_rec(5, 'a', 'b');
}
```

Also, since the function is defined as returning `void`, change the `return 0;` above to `return;`. If you want, you can also simplify it like this:

```
void string_rec(int num, char ch1, char ch2)
{
    if (num != 0)
        return;
    printf("%c", ch1);
    string_rec(num - 1, ch1, ch2);
    printf("%c%c", ch2, ch2);

}
```

Comment: Or just replace `else { ... }` with `...` to avoid indenting the entire function

Comment: still doesnt work somehow... the updated code is                             #include<stdio.h>
void string_rec(int num, char ch1, char ch2)
{
 if (num != 0)
 {
  printf("%c",ch1);
  return string_rec(num-1, ch1, ch2);
   printf("%c%c", ch2, ch2);
 }
}
void main()
{
 int num;
 char ch1, ch2;
 printf("type a num and 2 letters to get the strig\n");
 scanf("%d %c %c", &num, &ch1, &ch2);
 string_rec(num, ch1, ch2);
}                                                                                                                                    it still prints "aaa"

Comment: @BenLa You didn't remove the `return` in your updated code.

Comment: @BenLa yes, and I'm telling you to remove the `return` in front of the `string_rec(num-1, ch1, ch2); `. That's why your code is not working. Because of the `return` that you have there.

Comment: ok I fixed it...but they tought us to put the return before calling the function. and that is the structure of recursion. can u explain why? this is just in case of int function?

Comment: @BenLa think about the structure of this program. What do you need to return from the recursive call? All it does is printing. There's nothing to return, so you don't need a `return` there. The reason why you often have a `return` in recursive calls is because the function needs the data returned from the recursive call.

Comment: got it thanks so most/all of the times in void functions i wouldnt need a return!

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove return keyword, Bcz void type they can't return anything that why you're getting the warring.

Follow the below code maybe that help you find your solution.

> - code

```
void string_rec(int num, char ch1, char ch2)
{
    if (num == 0)
        return;
    else
    {
        printf("%c",ch1);
        string_rec(num-1, ch1, ch2);
        printf("%c%c", ch2, ch2);
    }
}
```